# How to group by part of the columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I selected some of the columns, `DATE` column is `datetime`, I want to only group by the receipt header id and receipt detail item category, but I run the SQL, I get an error. How to run successfully?

```
select 
    DATE as DATE, 
    RECEIPT_ID,
    CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2,
    SUM(CEILING(TOTAL_QTY / MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY)) AS Qty,
    SUM(ROUND(CEILING(TOTAL_QTY / MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY) * 
        ROUND(MEASURE.LENGTH * MEASURE.WIDTH * MEASURE.HEIGHT/ 1000000.0, 9), 2)) AS cbm
from 
    RECEIPT 
left join 
    MEASURE ON MEASURE.item = RECEIPT.ITEM 
            AND MEASURE.company = RECEIPT.COMPANY
where
    MEASURE.QUANTITY_UM = 'ctn'
group by 
    RECEIPT_ID, CATEGORY1
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: CATEGORY2, needs to be added to the group by in order for your query to work.

Comment: @isaace as well as the date (first selected column)

Comment: since date is a date time you may need to SELECT `CONVERT(date, [date])` and group by `CONVERT(date, [date])` as well  if you want the records grouped by day.

Comment: Can't, and doesn't make sense to not group the non-aggregated columns.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** group by all non-aggregated columns which are part of your select clause. I have modified your query to do just that - please see below.
If you have a need to `GROUP BY` just by RECEIPT_ID and category1, you wouldn't have a need to display those other two columns (date and category2), as they would have been merged.

```
   SELECT 
      DATE as DATE, 
      RECEIPT_ID,
      CATEGORY1, 
      CATEGORY2,
      SUM(CEILING( TOTAL_QTY /MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY )) as Qty,
      SUM(Round( CEILING( TOTAL_QTY /MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY )* Round( MEASURE.LENGTH * MEASURE.WIDTH * MEASURE.HEIGHT/ 1000000.0, 9 ), 2 )) as cbm
   from RECEIPT 
   left join MEASURE on MEASURE.item = RECEIPT.ITEM AND MEASURE.company = RECEIPT.COMPANY
   WHERE MEASURE.QUANTITY_UM = 'ctn'
  GROUP BY Date, RECEIPT_ID, CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't grouping on `DATE` or `Category2`, remove them from your query:

```
 select RECEIPT_ID,
   CATEGORY1, 
   SUM(CEILING( TOTAL_QTY /MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY )) as Qty,
   SUM(Round( CEILING( TOTAL_QTY /MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY )* Round( MEASURE.LENGTH * MEASURE.WIDTH * MEASURE.HEIGHT/ 1000000.0, 9 ), 2 )) as cbm
   from RECEIPT 
   left join MEASURE on MEASURE.item = RECEIPT.ITEM AND MEASURE.company = RECEIPT.COMPANY
   WHERE MEASURE.QUANTITY_UM = 'ctn'
   group by RECEIPT_ID, CATEGORY1
```

When using `GROUP BY` SQL requires that all fields in your `SELECT` clause are either:

1. Listed in your `GROUP BY` clause or
2. Contained inside aggregate functions (e.g., `MIN`, `SUM`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error you are getting is:

```
 Column 'XXXXX' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

You must GROUP BY the other columns you are selecting (aside from sums) or do some compound query in order to get the data you need

```
      group by DATE, RECEIPT_ID, CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to use GROUP BY in you query you must mention all the other columns selected other than those that are in you AGGREGATE functions.Coz,the GROUP BY occurs based on the other columns in the selection.Hence you cannot have all the columns in the Select CLAUSE.

As per the requirement description you have posted, i.e you need to group by RECEIPT_ID and CATEGORY1 and CATEGORY2 your query should be something like the below

```
select 
   RECEIPT_ID,
   CATEGORY1, 
   CATEGORY2,
   SUM(CEILING( TOTAL_QTY /MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY )) as Qty,
   SUM(Round( CEILING( TOTAL_QTY /MEASURE.CONVERSION_QTY )* Round( MEASURE.LENGTH * MEASURE.WIDTH * MEASURE.HEIGHT/ 1000000.0, 9 ), 2 )) as cbm
   from RECEIPT 
   left join MEASURE on MEASURE.item = RECEIPT.ITEM AND MEASURE.company = RECEIPT.COMPANY
   WHERE MEASURE.QUANTITY_UM = 'ctn'
   group by RECEIPT_ID, CATEGORY1,CATEGORY2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have aggregate functions in your SQL, all your non-aggregate columns have to be present in the group by clause. As a work-around, you can use for example union, so in the 1st SQL clause you do

`SELECT RECEIPT_ID, CATEGORY1` and the SUMs, and in the 2nd query you get the rest of the columns